# Is there an equivalent of Groovy Closures in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, groovy

I am trying to port some Groovy code to Python, and I am wondering how I can best emulate Groovy Closure functionality in Python.

I am unsure whether Python's closures are the same thing, or if a lambda function would more closely match what Groovy lang calls a Closure.

I was wondering if anyone had experience or advice related to this dilemma.

Comment: IMHO lambda closest to closure. Otherwise just a function.

Comment: @daggett Thank you so much for the feedback. I will give that a shot!